# is NServiceBus useful in this WCF MVC scenario?

Tags: c#, wcf, nservicebus

I just started investigating nservicebus, and can't figure out of it's appropriate or maybe overkill for my particular situation. Architectural pointers are greatly appreciated, i'm struggling a bit.

I have an MVC website and WCF REST service that both receive messages, e.g. "post a question". This should trigger a number of actions, like storage of the enity, examiniation by a rules engine, and maybe sending a push message, updating some aggregate data. The result of the rules engine might also cause a new message to be created. These requirements may change in the future. I would like to implement this in a way where the receiving endpoint sends out a message to anyone who happens to be listening (person X created a new question).

I was thinking of storing the messages in a db table and having my modules monitor the table. This thought process was moved to msmq and then to pub sub using nservicebus. However, I'm not sure how this should be implemented.

I'm currently thinking about the following scenario. A question comes into the WCF REST service. The WCF service persists the question and publishes a new question message (so it would need to host nservicebus somehow?). My modules subscribed to the message take action, like send out a notification or trigger an action based on the defined rules.

Is this a scenario where pub sub using nservicebus will benefit me? And would this be the way to go about actually implmenting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The WCF service persists the question and publishes a new question
>   message (so it would need to host nservicebus somehow?)

NServiceBus can be hosted in any managed process, including IIS. To do this (inside WCF service)

- Create an instance of IBus when your WCF service starts up.
- When you receive a question request into the service assemble your NServiceBus message
- Publish the messages by using IBus.Publish(MyMessage);

To create an instance of IBus in IIS a common method is to use the fluent configuration inside your global asmx. A typical configuration would look something like

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static IBus Bus { get; private set; }

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.WithWeb()
            .Log4Net()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
                .IsTransactional(false)
                .PurgeOnStartup(false)
            .UnicastBus()
                .ImpersonateSender(false)
            .CreateBus()
            .Start();
    }
```

You define your NServiceBus endpoint (Queues) using the web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" 
             type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
</configSections>

<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="WebFrontEnd" 
                     ErrorQueue="error" 
                     NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" 
                     MaxRetries="5" />
```

> My modules subscribed to the message take action

Your downstream subscribers can each be hosted inside the NServiceBus generic host running as a windows service, which is probably the easiest hosting option. The subscribers would each have a message handler class which implements *IHandleMessages*.

The way pub/sub works in NServiceBus:

1. A publisher service has an input queue and a subscription store.
2. A subscriber service has an input queue
3. The subscriber, on start-up will send a subscription message to the input queue of the publisher
4. The subscription message contains the type of message subscriber is interested in and the subscribers queue address
5. The publisher records the subscription in the subscription store.
6. The publisher receives a message.
7. The publisher evaluates the message type against the list of subscriptions
8. For each match found the publisher sends the message to the queue address.

You should probably download the NServiceBus pub-sub sample to gain a better understanding of this.

Comment: Thanx for this. I have in fact examined the pub sub sample (and all the others), but I was having some trouble getting all the parts in place. If I have an external facing WCF service and MVC site that receive post and user interactions can they both act as publishers to the same queue (triggering the same subscribers downstream)?

Comment: While that's probably possible to configure, something feels wrong to have multiple publishers for a single subscriber. The idea behind a subscriber is that you are interested in business events coming from a single place. If you have two sources of the events then you should probably have a separately hosted endpoint to receive those events, which would homogenise them and then publish them as one source. Kind of like the *Normalizer* design pattern http://www.eaipatterns.com/Normalizer.html

Comment: It's a common scenario though right? I can place an order by phone or order it online? I can understand that publishing from the one source would be better design. One more question: if I receive a question object.. do I pas this around using the queue (and IMessage), or is better to persist and pass around the id)?

Comment: If the question is truly huge (megabytes), or you have massive throughput/low latency requirement you may want to persist it. Otherwise just pass the data around. As long as you use transactional queues you won't lose anything.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would use NSB in place of WCF, not in addition to WCF. Service Buses introduce many new concepts and designs. the idea of asynchronous work is very different that traditional request/response.

To start, I would introduce a service bus until it's needed, that is until the request/response design becomes the bottleneck itself. A service bus isn't something you just "drop in" to an application. when introducing a service bus to an existing application you have to think through how eventually processing the command/event/message will impact the system which was designed using an imediate response & request.

Comment: I am indeed struggling a bit on how to combine the technologies (yes I looked and the WCF Integration sample). The (conceptual) problem I have is this: A user send a message from a device using REST (json). Is it then not a viable scenario to handle this communication using WCF, place the event in the queue using Nservicebus and have another process pick this up asynchronously?

Comment: NSB will send send the message, then NSB (either the same instance or another) will pick up the message and process it. I fail to see why SCF is needed at all though, because your MVC application can handle REST. so even with our without NSB, WCF seems like noise.

Comment: I'm using WCF because I don't want to handle these async javascript calls using MVC. More importantly, a native phone app will generate the same type of messages, so a service seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that your REST API is handling GETs and you'd like to turn some of your PUTs/POSTs/DELETEs into "async" calls.  You can use the built-in WCF integration endpoint, but you are tied to a SOAP binding.  You can hack in REST, but now you have essentially 2 endpoints, one for GETs and one for everything else.

We've integrated the two but bootstrapping NSB into WCF similar to the other answer(we use a HttpModule).  For change operations, we simply Bus.Send() the message to another endpoint and return to the client.  The receiving endpoint simply processes the message as needed.

If you require a pipeline of logic, that is built-in.  You can string message handlers together to process in a defined sequence.  I'm thinking you may not need Pub/Sub at all if this is the effect you desire.  This keeps down the number of endpoints.  If the endpoint gets overloaded, we can scale out by adding a Distributor, but that is another story.

Comment: we have made a design decision to use REST (and json) and this is indeed the reason I figured the integration endpoint won't work for us. I was trying to figure out using the documentation what exactly the difference in practice is, between send and publish, but all I'm getting is a purpose: pub is for events that already happened and send for events that haven't happened yet?

Comment: Send is for a Command you are issuing to the Domain Model(if you have one).  So your Send is telling the system to add a message.  The Event would be the effect of adding that message.  I've found in practice that many times you don't really need Pub/Sub, a simple Send plus the pipeline is enough.

Comment: do I need to do something special in my WCF publisher config? My mvc app is currently a subscriber. It works with the publisher from the pub sub sample (using the nservicebus host) but not with my WCF service (standard config in global.asax using msmqsubscriptionstorage). No messages appear in the queue?

Comment: Your WCF should only Bus.Send() to another endpoint that does the Bus.Publish().  Then you can use the sample straight up.  What types of events does the MVC app listen to?  I'm thinking it would be easier to just grab any data after it has been entered.